# Android OpenGL ES 2.0 : Translation, collision and control over framerate

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, physics-engine

I try to design my own game engine on Android, with OpenGL ES 2.0.

So far, I have a sphere moving along the x axis with the equation x(t) = v*(t-t0) + x0. Let's say the radius of the sphere is r. I use the fonction `SystemClock.uptimeMillis()` to compute the time `t`.

There are two walls, at x=1 and x=-1. When the sphere touches one of these two walls (i.e. when the distance between the sphere and one wall is less than r), then it bounces back.

My calculations are done in the `onDrawFrame()` method of my renderer.

Therefore, the calculations are only done when a frame is rendered. So, the frequency of the "collision check" depends on the framerate of the application. Alas, sometimes the next frame takes too long to be rendered and the translation takes the sphere behind the wall, like some kind of quantum particle :).

Is it possible to have some kind of control over the framerate of my application ? Do you know a method to avoid such discontinuities in the trajectory of my sphere ?

Thank you very much for your held !

Answer (score 0):

"Tunneling" through walls is a consistent problem in video games.  Much time is spent combating such behavior.  When checking your collisions, you really need to know the previous position and the new position.  Then you check to see if there is a wall in between those two positions, and if so, you re-orient your object as though it had bounced off of the wall.

A collision check that looks for distance between sphere and wall is not enough.

Comment: This is exactly what I do. But the issue is that the walls are rotating, and sometimes the old position is off the wall because of the rotation.